lost funds when trading and then closing and withdrawing to my account
I am new to this having only been trading meme coins for about 2 weeks but i cant help but notice none of my money is coming back to my Wallet. Am i doing something wrong? i have a Phantom wallet and it is connected to DEX screener so that i can trade (i use them because i have a very small portfolio only around 50 dollars). I have executed 6 trades which in theory should bring my account up to around 95 dollars however instead it is not coming into my wallet and i have only 7 dollars left. I have checked and every trade i have made has resulted in a solid profit so i don't think its any fees taxing me into a loss. Just need some help please
